# Is a table larger than max filesize of filesystem possible?

Tags: mysql

From what I understand MySQLs maximal table size depends on the filesystem's maximal size of a single file.

I need to store about 300 TB of binary data (tons of images), preferably in one table. Is this a good idea? Can I make MySQL store a single table in several files? What problems are likely to occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a way to have mysql store blobs seperatly, but it seems like it might be easier to store the images as regular files and just include the path of the file in the table.  You should look at how Squid stores images for effient lookup.

Comment: Partitioning seems to be the solution. From the MySQL documentation:

_Partitioning makes it possible to store more data in one table than can be held on a single disk or file system partition._